# How key is mapped to value in a hasmap in java with O(1) get() method?

Tags: java, hashmap, mapping

Consider an int array variable x[]. The variable X will have starting address reference. When array is accessed with index 2 that is x[2].then its memory location is calculated as

address of x[2] is starting addr + index * size of int.

ie. x[2]=x + 2*4.

But in case of hashmap how the memory address will be mapped internally.

By reading many previous posts I observed that HashMap uses a linked list to store the key value list. But if that is the case, then to find a key, it generates a hashcode then it will checks for equal hash code in list and retrieves the value..

This takes O(n) complexity. 
If i am wrong in above observation Please correct me... I am a beginner. 
Thank you

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-internal

Comment: Most of the time there's only one thing in the list.  Sometimes two or three.  Certainly not n.  So it's not O(n).

Comment: @DavidWallace - There is only one thing in the list that has that hash.  I think the OP believes the implementation has to compare the hash value to everything in the list until it finds the right one.  I've posted an answer explaining that difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional implementation of a HashMap is to use a function to generate a key, then use that key to access a value directly.  Think of it as generating something that will translate into an array index.  It does not look through the hashmap comparing element hashes to the generated hash; it generates the hash, and uses the hash to access an element directly.

What I think you're talking about is the case where two values in the HashMap generate the SAME key.  THEN it uses a list of those, and has to look through them to determine which one it wants.  But that's not O(n) where n is the number of elements in the HashMap, just O(m) where m is the number of elements with the same hash.  Clearly the name of the game is to find a hash function where the generated hash is unique for all the elements, as much as is feasible.

--- edit to expand on the explanation ---

In your post, you state:

> By reading many previous posts I observed that HashMap uses a linked
>   list to store the key value list.

This is wrong for the overall HashMap.  For a HashMap to work reasonably, there must be a way to use the key to calculate a way to access the corresponding element directly, not by searching through all the values in the HashMap.

A "perfect" hash calculation would translate each possible key into hash value that was not calculated for any other key.  This is usually not feasible, and so it is usually possible that two different keys will result in the same result from the hash calculation.  In this case, the HashMap implementation could use a linked list of values, and would need to look through all such values to find the one that it was looking for.  But this number is FAR less than the number of values in the overall HashMap.

You can make a hash where strings are the keys, and in which the first character of the string is converted to a number which is then used as an array index.  As long as your strings all have different first characters, then accessing the value is a simple calc plus an array access -- O(1).  Or you could add all the character values of the string indices together and take the last two (or three) digits, and THAT would be your hash calc.  As long as the addition produced unique values for each index string, you don't ever have to look through a list; again, O(1).

And, in fact, as long as the hash calculation is approximately perfect, the lookup is still O(1) overall, because the limited number of times you have to look through a short list does not alter the overall efficiency.

Comment: I would like to add that when the array containing the hashmap reaches 75% capacity utilization, the array is doubled, and all of the data redistributed as per the hash function into the new array, making collisions less likely. Of course, copying takes time but, performance is still O(n) ammortized performance. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis

Comment: I edited my question. please check the question again. Sorry for the inconvenience.